# After sharding(no any data), one shard contains more chunks than others

Tags: mongodb

I have 3 configsvr, 70 shardsvr:

1. enableSharding the database;
2. shardCollection by mongo shell `load("shard.ms")`, the content:

   `sh.shardCollection('test.info150831', {_id: 'hashed'});`

   ....

   `sh.shardCollection('test.info150915', {_id: 'hashed'});`
3. Such as the title. After I shard these collections, I run mongo shell `sh.status()`. I find that `shard0000` have much more chunks than others, why?

Comment: How many chunks total in the sharded collection? Is the balancer enabled? Post your sh.status() if you can't find those values to edit into the body of the question.

Comment: MongoDB version would be nice, as would the output of sh.status() - as an initial guess I will bet that the test DB has shard0000 as its primary shard and you are hitting some contention having all of the collections starting out on that initial shard.  You would probably have more luck if you used multiple databases (one per shard at a minimum for efficiency) as well as multiple collections.